# storing and retrieving data from sqlite database?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am creating android alarm app in that I have to store alarms in sqlite data base but I cannot make it out. I am getting problem at listadapter and cursor getalarm() method anyone can help me how to store data and retrieve from sqlite database thanks in advance.

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ALARM";
private Object databaseHelper;

public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context, String name,
        CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    try {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE alarms(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, sHour INTEGER, sMinute INTEGER )");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState,
        MyDatabaseHelper databaseHelper, int hour, int minute) {

    // super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_db);
    databaseHelper.addAlarm("hour", hour);
    databaseHelper.addAlarm("minute", minute);
}

private void setContentView(int activityAlarmDb) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void addAlarm(String hour, int minute)

{

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(2);

    values.put("hour", hour);

    values.put("minute", minute);

    getWritableDatabase().insert("hour", "minute", values);

}

public Cursor getAlarm()

{

    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select * from alarm",
            null);
    // Cursor AllFriends = databaseHelper.getAlarm();
    Cursor getAlarm = databaseHelper.getAlarm();

    getAlarm.moveToFirst();

    while (!getAlarm.isAfterLast()) {

        String Name = getAlarm.getString(1);

        int number = getAlarm.getInt(2);

        getAlarm.moveToNext();
        String[] from = { "name", "phonenumber" };

        int[] to = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, getAlarm, from, to);

        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        myList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

private ListView findViewById(int list) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS alarms");
    onCreate(db);

}
}
```

Comment: The table you create is called `alarms`, yet you do `"SELECT * FROM alarm`

Comment: but i am getting error at Cursor getAlarm = databaseHelper.getAlarm();
and ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, getAlarm, from, to);